# How to avoid nested Single in RxJava2

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I am fairly new in RxJava pradigm. I am doing following is leading to nested Single objects.

```
  tickHappened.map{
    func(it)
  }
  //I get Single<Single<ArrayList<String>>>
```

Here `tickHappened:Single<T>` and `func<T>(T param):Single<ArrayList<String>>`

```
  tickHappened.map{
    func(it)
  }
  //I get Single<Single<ArrayList<String>>>
   .map { single ->
            single.map { list ->
                list.size
            }
        }
```

I actually need to return `Single<Int>` which is the size of the Arraylist passed. I need to use map twice in the above chain which leads to `Single<Single<Int>>`

Is there a way to avoid nesting Singles? If I understand Rxjava, it doesn't make sense to have a Single which enclose another Single? If not, then is there a way to return `Single<Int>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner, one thing to learn is the [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) operator that is available all around RxJava and is the most common operator needed for solving problems:

```
tickHappened
    .flatMap { func(it) }
    .map { it.size() }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried flatmap, but my editor was giving unknown reference error, so I believed with my half knowledge that flatmap won't apply on nested single. It worked, and also clarified the difference between flatmap and map.