# Vert.x Reactive Kafka client: chaining not working when writing?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, vert.x

I am using `io.vertx.reactivex.kafka.client.producer.KafkaProducer` client. The client has a 
`rxWrite` function which returns `Single<RecordMetadata>`. However I need to log error if any, during write operation. It apparently is not getting executed.

I have written following working example.

**test():** Function to test the chaining and logging

```
    fun test(): Single<Int> {
    val data = Single.just(ArrayList<String>().apply {
        add("Hello")
        add("World")
    })

    data.flattenAsObservable<String> { list -> list }
        .flatMap { advertiser ->
       //does not work with writeKafka
            writeError(advertiser).toObservable().doOnError({ println("Error $data") })
        }
        .subscribe({ record -> println(record) }, { e -> println("Error2 $e") })

    return data.map { it.size }
}
```

**writeKafka:**  Writes the given given string into Kafka and returns Single

```
fun writeKafka(param: String): Single<RecordMetadata> {
 //null topic to produce IllegalArgumentException()
    val record = KafkaProducerRecord.create(null, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), param)
    return kafkaProducer.rxWrite(record)
}
```

**writeError:** Always return a single with error of same type

```
fun writeError(param: String): Single<RecordMetadata> {
    return Single.error<RecordMetadata>(IllegalArgumentException())
}
```

So when I call `writeKafka` It only prints `Error2` but if I use `writeError` it prints both `Error` and `Error2`. Looks like the single returned by `writeKafka` is still waiting for result, but then why even `Error2` is printed?

I am pretty newbie in RxJava2, could somebody point out any error in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to read and post the stacktrace of errors so that the problem can be isolated.

In this case, looks like you get the `IllegalArgumentException` from `create` and you don't get any `Single` because the relevant Kafka class [throws it](https://github.com/jkreps/kafka-clients-prototype/blob/master/src/main/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.java#L27). `return kafkaProducer.rxWrite(record)` never executes at all and you practically crash the `flatMap`. `doOnError` never gets into play hence only the "Error2" is printed.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd, for noticing another stupid mistake of mine.